# How to use scss variables in create react app?

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app

I create my app with `create-react-app` and I try to use shared scss files. I have folder with them files `common/styles/`. And also I have some scss files there (`_reset.scss, _variables.scss`).

My _variables.scss:

```
$color-main: #1E700F;
```

My index.scss:

```
@import "variables";
```

Then I connect my `index.scss` and my `index.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './common/styles/index.scss';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Then I create `Button` component in folder `common/components/Button`. And I want to use  in my `Button.scss` next code:

```
.button {
  border: 1px solid $color-main;
  color: $color-main;
}
```

After I import my `Button.scss` to `Button.js` file I have next error:

```
SassError: Undefined variable: "$color-main".
```

Comment: When writing mixins and functions that take arguments, you usually want to ensure that those arguments have the types and formats your API expects.

Comment: you may get a solution on simple googling. try that first. we will help you if you get any issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be importing scss in the js file. Instead create a sub folder inside your scss and name it components. Then create a scss file specific for such component which is "button" for  you. Then import it like this in your index.scss

```
@import "variables";
@import "reset";
@import "components/button" <-- your button scss should be under the variables
```

Comment: I guess This will add the all css in the final bundle, which is a bad practice. is there any other way to prevent this?

Comment: check this out: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin